# What is the time complexity of dart List.insert in Dart?

Tags: dart

From my understanding of Lists in Dart, it seems like they behave like vectors from C++. So, let's say, if I were to insert an element at the beginning of the list, it would shift the remaining elements out, leading to a time complexity of O(length of the list). Can someone confirm if that is how it works?

```
final numbers = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4];
const index = 0;
numbers.insert(index, 10);
print(numbers); // [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) explain that `List`s are arrays.  The documentation for [`List.insert`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/insert.html) also explains that insertion shifts remaining elements, indicating O(n) behavior.

Comment: Yes, can confirm that's how the built-in growable list works (also when compiled to JavaScript, because that's how the JavaScript `Array` works too). If you want to add at both ends of the list, use a `Queue` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this dart code:

```dart
void measureInsertAndAddTime(int size) {
  List<int> testList = List.generate(size, (index) => index);

  Stopwatch addStopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
  testList.add(0);
  print('add done in ${addStopwatch.elapsed}');

  Stopwatch insertstopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
  testList.insert(0, 0);
  print('insert done in ${insertstopwatch.elapsed}');
}

void main() {
  for (int i = 10; i <= 100000000; i *= 10) {
    print("for list of size: $i");
    measureInsertAndAddTime(i);
  }
}
```

here is the results of my execution:

```
for list of size: 10
add done in 0:00:00.000343
insert done in 0:00:00.000245
for list of size: 100
add done in 0:00:00.000001
insert done in 0:00:00.000010
for list of size: 1000
add done in 0:00:00.000001
insert done in 0:00:00.000056
for list of size: 10000
add done in 0:00:00.000001
insert done in 0:00:00.000627
for list of size: 100000
add done in 0:00:00.000010
insert done in 0:00:00.002558
for list of size: 1000000
add done in 0:00:00.000004
insert done in 0:00:00.013539
for list of size: 10000000
add done in 0:00:00.000004
insert done in 0:00:00.116381
for list of size: 100000000
add done in 0:00:00.000005
insert done in 0:00:01.184865
```

as you can see `add` function has an O(1) complexity. and is constant for all different list sizes. but the `insert` function seems to have O(n). if it behaves like vectors it must remain constant. so I think the `insert` is actually shifting.